# The "Finish" Command in the Eclipse C++ Project Creation Wizard is not Working

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm trying to create a simple C++ HelloWorld project in Eclipse, but when I go through the creation wizard and click the finish button, nothing happens. The wizard doesn't close, and a project is not created. I'm creating a Hello World C++ project, and using the MinGW GCC toolchain. Is there an explanation as to why this is happening?

Comment: Is the `Finish` button enabled? Have you inserted the name of the project?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find out exactly what the problem was, but I reinstalled Eclipse and made sure to use the C++ IDE this time (last installation I installed the Java IDE and added C++ afterwards), and I was able to make a basic application with no problems.